# Strange constant message im mail.log: lost connection after AUTH from unknown

Tags: postfix, fail2ban

Anyone can help me understanding this message that keeps appearing in my mail.log:

```
Dec  6 19:53:53 localhost postfix/smtpd[4873]: connect from unknown[185.234.219.94]
Dec  6 19:53:53 localhost postfix/smtpd[4873]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[185.234.219.94]
Dec  6 19:53:53 localhost postfix/smtpd[4873]: disconnect from unknown[185.234.219.94] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
```

I have fail2ban installed but it seems that is not block this IP. Can you help setting fail2ban to block this IP for a certain time? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find new filer on gihub for fail2ban
"postfix-failedauth - new proposed filter"

https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2200

Regards

Comment: it worked perfectly! Thank you.